# Sort 100x100 array with numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have an array, size 100x100, with random numbers from 1 to 20. I have to sort table by row. I've tried to use this command:

```
def shedule(self):
    a=self.arr
    a.sort()
    print(self.arr)
```

but the result shows the numbers in this sequence (first row):

```
    ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '10' '10' '10' '10' '10' '10'
  '11' '11' '11' '11' '11' '12' '12' '13' '13' '13' '13' '14' '14' '14'
  '14' '15' '16' '16' '16' '16' '16' '17' '17' '17' '17' '17' '18' '18'
  '18' '19' '19' '19' '19' '2' '2' '2' '2' '2' '2' '20' '20' '20' '20'
  '3' '3' '3' '3' '3' '4' '4' '4' '4' '4' '4' '4' '4' '4' '4' '5' '5' '5'
  '5' '6' '6' '6' '6' '6' '6' '6' '6' '7' '7' '7' '7' '8' '8' '9' '9' '9'
  '9' '9' '9' '9' '9']]
```

Comment: `arr.sort(axis=1)`

Comment: are these strings rather than ints. as your sort looks like its done string wise sort rather than numerical sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your elements are strings and not integers, you need to convert your elements to integers with `self.arr = self.arr.astype('int32')` and then you can do `self.arr.sort(axis=1)`

```
def shedule(self):
     self.arr = self.arr.astype('int32')
     self.arr.sort(axis=1)
     print(self.arr)
```

Comment: I did it, know my method looks like this: `def shedule(self):
        a=self.arr
        self.arr = self.arr.astype('int32')
        a.sort(axis=1)
        print(self.arr)` but the result i so random ` 8 15  6  6 12 18 17  6  8 15 15 19 13 13  5  9  5  9 20  2  6  2  6  6
  16  7  1  9  1 10 11  8 11 12  9 19 20  6 14 15 16 10  2 12 15 16 11  4
  11 12  8  6  4 11 14  5  6 13 14 19  4 19  1 14  2 12 18  4  6  6  3  9
  16 16 18  4 18 16  2 16 16  5 11  2 15 15 12 15 10  3  9 13 10  3 18 13
   2 12 10 15`. When I print(a) not arr, I have same result as before

Comment: unfortunately not, there will be more details in the new reply

Comment: @BartoszSochacki Check my edit, you were switching between using `a` and `self.arr` it appears this is part of a class, if you want to permenently change it then you should be doing your operations on `self.arr` if just want to print it out and not change it, then use `a = self.arr` and change all of the `self.arr` in my example to `a`

Comment: Okey, it work. Thank you very much, I cant handle with this problem for day.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems. first you have strings instead of numbers second you array is 2 dimensional , in other terms 2 axis so you have to specify the axis you want to touch I believe here you talking about the columns -- That would axis=1.
**Please also remember the size is basically length, you cannot have 100*100; that is the shape**